# Q: 'Polygon' object has no property 'normed' in model hddm

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I started to run the example with its self data in hddm model, I got this wrong.
`'Polygon' object has no property 'normed' in model hddm`

So, **how to make this function "plot_posterior_predictive" work?**

I have tried some methods to deal with it but I failed to address this problems.
I attempt to downgrade matplotlib into the version of 3.2.0, it doesn't work.
Howerver, some other plot function could work like plot_posterior_quantiles, plot_posteriors and plot_posteriors_conditions.
So, I think the problem is about kabuki other than matplotlib.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8540e2e64635> in <module>
----> 1 m.plot_posterior_predictive()

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\hddm\models\base.py in plot_posterior_predictive(self, *args, **kwargs)
    766         if 'value_range' not in kwargs:
    767             kwargs['value_range'] = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
--> 768         kabuki.analyze.plot_posterior_predictive(self, *args, **kwargs)
    769 
    770     def plot_posterior_quantiles(self, *args, **kwargs):

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\kabuki\analyze.py in plot_posterior_predictive(model, plot_func, required_method, columns, save, path, figsize, format, num_subjs, **kwargs)
    558                 ax.set_title(str(bottom_node['subj_idx']))
    559 
--> 560             plot_func(bottom_node['node'], ax, **kwargs)
    561 
    562             if num_subjs is not None and i >= num_subjs:

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\kabuki\analyze.py in _plot_posterior_pdf_node(bottom_node, axis, value_range, samples, bins)
    476     # Plot data
    477     if len(bottom_node.value) != 0:
--> 478         axis.hist(bottom_node.value.values, normed=True, color='r',
    479                   range=(value_range[0], value_range[-1]), label='data',
    480                   bins=bins, histtype='step', lw=2.)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   6817             if patch:
   6818                 p = patch[0]
-> 6819                 p.update(kwargs)
   6820                 if lbl is not None:
   6821                     p.set_label(lbl)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in update(self, props)
   1004 
   1005         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
-> 1006             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
   1007 
   1008         if len(ret):

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1004 
   1005         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
-> 1006             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
   1007 
   1008         if len(ret):

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in _update_property(self, k, v)
    999                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
   1000                 if not callable(func):
-> 1001                     raise AttributeError('{!r} object has no property {!r}'
   1002                                          .format(type(self).__name__, k))
   1003                 return func(v)

AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no property 'normed'
```

Comment: You should put a code sample that allows the problem to be reproduced, and you can just leave in the error to showcase what it says and the line at which it's made.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problems caused by "kabuki" package which used the deprecated arg "normed =Ture"

So, We just manage to revise this code and everything will be fine.
In the "analyze.py", line in 478, convert "normed=True" to "density=True" as follow.

```
# Plot data
    if len(bottom_node.value) != 0:
        axis.hist(bottom_node.value.values, density=True, color='r',
                  range=(value_range[0], value_range[-1]), label='data',
                  bins=bins, histtype='step', lw=2.)
```